# PyCharm crashing at startup

Tags: pycharm

Since a few days, `PyCharm 2016.1.2` is crashing immediately at startup on my Mac (`OS X.10.5`).
I have tried to reinstall the IDE from scratch (i.e. deleting the app + everything concerning PyCharm in `~/Library`) but it doesn't solve the problem.
I have also checked the IDE logs (in `~/Library/Logs/PyCharm`) but there is no error here.
The only information available comes from the OS error box:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000303620
```

Note that I also use IntellijIdea on the same computer and I don't have any issues with it. Thanks for any information or advice.

Comment: Has anything changed since it was last working properly? OS update, software update, settings change, etc?

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but there is a 2016.1.3 now available.

Comment: I'm having the same problem right after I upgraded to the latest PyCharm. It crashes at startup, before I get the chance to accept the license agreement. My version is 2016.1.3. And the error is:
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT

Comment: I just got the same issue with the last update of IntellijIdea.

Comment: I was finally able to restore both software by downgrading to older versions (Intellij 15 and PyCharm 2016.1). Seems to be a bug in recent versions of the IDEs...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to "fix" the issue by upgrade to OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, I can't test that since El Capitan is not yet supported by my IT department...

Answer (score 0):

Under the package container of pycharm ,you will find file info.plist. 
open the file and search for JVMVersion and remove 1.8+ from that and save it.
You JVMVersion should look like below-

```
**<key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.8*</string>**
```

save and now open the pycharm.